# Wiener sausage of a Brownian motion with coordinates scaled differently

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

The Wiener sausage of a standard Brownian motion $\{W(t),0 \leq t \leq T\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set $S(T,R)=\bigcup_{0 \leq t \leq T} W(t)+B(0,R)$, where $B(x,r)$ denotes a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

It is well-known (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Wiener_sausage) that for any fixed $R>0$ $\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S(T,R))=(1+o(1))2\pi T/\log(T)$ as $T \to +\infty$.

For fixed $a>0,b>0, u>0$ denote by $S'(a,b,R)=\bigcup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} (a W_1(t),b W_2(t))^{\top}+B(0,R)$, where $W_1(t),W_2(t)$ are the first and the second component of $W(t)$ respectively.

I would like to ask,  are there any results, asymptotics for
$\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S'(u^{\gamma_1},u^{\gamma_2},R))$ as $u \to +\infty$ for fixed $\gamma_1\geq 0,\gamma_2\geq 0$? Clearly, if $\gamma_1=\gamma_2$, then $S'(u^{\gamma_1},u^{\gamma_2},R)=S(u^{2\gamma_1},R)$, so $\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S'(u^{\gamma_1},u^{\gamma_2},R))=(1+o(1))2\pi \frac{u^{2\gamma_2}}{2\gamma_2\log(u)}$ as $u\to+\infty$.

If $\gamma_1=0<\gamma_2$, then $\{u^{\gamma_2}W_1(t), \,0\leq t \leq 1\}$ has the same distribution as $\{W_1(t u^{2\gamma_2}), \,0\leq t \leq 1\}$, which is just a segment of length $\Theta(u^{\gamma_2})$, so, probably, $\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S'(1,u^{\gamma_2},R))=(1+o(1))C u^{\gamma_2}$ for some constant $C$.

On the other hand, if $0<\gamma_1<\gamma_2$, then seems that
$\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S'(u^{\gamma_1},u^{\gamma_2},R))\geq
\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S'(u^{\gamma_1},u^{\gamma_1},R))=(1+o(1))2\pi \frac{u^{2\gamma_1}}{2\gamma_1\log(u)}$. If $\gamma_1>\gamma_2/2$, then $2\pi\frac{u^{2\gamma_1}}{2\gamma_1\log(u)}\gg u^{\gamma_2}$, so even if $\gamma_1<\gamma_2$, $\gamma_1$ has its impact on the asymptotic of $\mathbb{E}\;Vol(S'(u^{\gamma_1},u^{\gamma_2},R))$.